# watson virtual agent preview : how to reset it ?

Tags: watson, watson-virtual-agent

I am discovering the IBM Virtual Agent product. The preview capability on the right of the screen is useful. However , I wonder how to reset it after a change in the customization .
The preview can be reset by closing the browser session:  is there another way that would allow to stay connected to the configuration environment ? .
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the Preview Pane by just refreshing your browser window rather than closing it altoghether. I have also passed this along to our team as feedback for further improvements to the preview pane in general. Thanks!